# Save a Python script's output with > in bash while using raw_input()

Tags: python, bash

This is a weird one that's so general I can't to properly narrow the search terms to find an answer.

My python script has a raw_input to prompt the user for values. But, when I try to run the script and funnel it into a file, it crashes.

Something like "script.py > save.txt"
wont work. It doesn't even properly prompt me at the command line for my input. There doesn't seem to be anything indicating why this doesn't work as intuitively as it should.

Comment: In what way does it "crash"?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you don't redirect the output?

Comment: Also, is it safe to assume that the "prompts" you are looking for are those given as argument to `raw_input`?

Comment: It doesn't give you a prompt because you are redirecting `stdout` to `save.txt`.  That's where the prompt goes.

Comment: To amplify @Dolda2000's comment below, if you are writing programs for the Unix environment, then you should design for non-interactive input. As an example `ls` would be far less useful with redirection and pipes if it asked questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`raw_output` prints its prompt to `stdout`, which you are redirecting to a file. So your prompt will end up in the file and the program does not appear to show a prompt. One solution is to output your prompt to `stderr`.

```
import sys

sys.stderr.write('prompt> ')
value = raw_input()
print('value was: ', value)
```

You could also avoid using both pipes and interactive input with the same script. Either take input from command line flags using `argparse` and use pipes, or create an interactive program that saves output to a file itself.

Depending on your program's logic, you can also check whether `stdout` is connected to a live console or not:

```
is_tty = os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())
```

Dolda2000 also has a good point about writing to `/dev/tty`, which will write to the controlling terminal of the script being run even if *both* `stdin` and `stderr` are redirected. The deal there, though, is that you can't use it if you're not running in a terminal.

```
import errno
try:
    with open('/dev/tty', 'w') as tty:
        tty.write('prompt> ')
except IOError as exc:
    if exc.errno == errno.ENXIO:
        pass # no /dev/tty available
    else:
        pass # something else went wrong
```

Comment: +1, but just for completeness, I would like to add that outputting the prompt to `stderr` is not necessarily a good idea, in case it too is redirected. To be more properly correct, one should probably open `/dev/tty` to do explicitly interactive I/O. But yes, in the majority of cases, it is probably better to simply avoid both redirection and interactive I/O in the same program.